# Excel VBA: End(xlUp) and End(xlDown) all end up at row 244, which is blank?

Tags: excel, vba, row

I filled B2:GQ244 with formulae, copied the range and pasted by value before sorting the range column by column. The cells in B8:GQ244 were all blanks. Then, I wanted to concatenate the non-blank cells column by column, starting from row 2. To do so, I needed to find the last non-blank cell in each column.

For some reason, both End(xlUp) and End(xlDown) gave row 244, which was empty. I can't figure out why. I thought the file might be corrupted. So, I copied the two sheets and the module to a newly created workbook to no avail. Any explanation why both End(xlUp) and End(xlDown) gave row 244?

```
.Range("B2:GQ244").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(FIND( B$1,Sheet9!$H34)),"""",Sheet9!$I34)"

'paste by value to get rid of formulae

.Range("B2:GQ244").Copy
.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'sort by column

Dim last_row As Long
Dim j As Long

For i = 2 To 200 Step 1

Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(245, i)).Sort key1:=.Cells(2, i), order1:=xlAscending

Next i

For i = 2 To 200 Step 1

last_row = .Cells(65536, i).End(xlUp).Row
last_row = .Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Row
```

Comment: A cell containing a formula isn't blank. It just displays nothing but it contains the formula.

Comment: @Variatus yes, but after pasting by value, the formulae were all gone.

Comment: Yes, the formulas are replaced with the values they created. I have explained this in my formal answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will remove all null strings at the bottom of columns as well as those that contain zeroes.

```
Sub ClearBlankCells()
    ' 146
    
    Dim Rng         As Range            ' working range
    Dim R           As Long             ' intermediate: row
    Dim C           As Long             ' loop counter: columns

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("B2:GQ244")
            .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(FIND( B$1,Sheet9!$H34)),"""",Sheet9!$I34)"
            ' replace formulas with their values
            .Copy
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        For C = 2 To 200 Step 1
            Set Rng = .Columns(C)
            R = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((" & Rng.Address & "<>"""")*(" & _
                                                      Rng.Address & "<>0)*1)")
            If R > 0 Then
                Set Rng = Range(.Cells(R + 1, C), .Cells(Rows.Count, C))
                Rng.ClearContents
            End If
            ' sort by column
'            Range(.Cells(2, C), .Cells(245, C)).Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, C), Order1:=xlAscending
        Next C
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that no blanks or zeroes may be included in the block of data above the bottom of each column, including the caption.

Sorting must be done after such cells have been removed but I left the sort instructions dimmed out because it's wrong either in syntax or by concept. If you need to sort each column the syntax is wrong because the syntax sorts the entire sheet. On the other hand, if you want to sort the entire sheet you don't have to do it in a loop 200 times.

The code runs very slowly which gives rise to two observations.

1. It spends 99% of its time repairing the damage it has done in its first line.
2. It looks at a data range which is vastly bigger than what is actually, reasonably, required. Nobody wants to look at a sheet 200 columns and 244 rows.

Therefore there must be much better ways to do achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to sort the column individually. B1:GQ1 contain names and the rows after them contain either page number of null. I sort the columns individually to see which name appears on which pages. This is for an index for a publication. There maybe a better way of doing it but I don't foresee doing this job again in the future. So, as long as I have a working method, it's fine. If I need to do this many times, I'll then investigate on how to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm your findings. Having a blank ActiveSheet and a blank Sheet9 the code below filled the ActiveSheet with zeroes B2:GQ244. It then read the last row xlUp as 244 and xlDown as 2. Both of these values are as expected. Perhaps you have a setting that suppresses the display of zeroes. However, as explained in my comment above, a cell that appears blank isn't necessarily blank and that would also apply to a cell containing a NullString inserted by your formula, even if the formula was subsequently removed leaving the null string in its place.

```
Sub Examine()
    
    Dim last_row As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("B2:GQ244").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(FIND( B$1,Sheet9!$H34)),"""",Sheet9!$I34)"
        
        'paste by value to get rid of formulae
        
        .Range("B2:GQ244").Copy
        .Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        'sort by column
        
        For i = 2 To 200 Step 1
            Range(.Cells(2, i), .Cells(245, i)).Sort Key1:=.Cells(2, i), Order1:=xlAscending
            last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            Debug.Print last_row            ' returns 244
            last_row = .Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Row
            Debug.Print last_row            ' returns 2
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The only mystery remaining, therefore, is why `.Cells(1, i).End(xlDown).Row` gives you a value of 244. It doesn't. Therefore the solution must be in the conduct of your test, not in its result. Compare your testing method with the one I employed above.

Comment: Strange that the code filled cells with zeroes. Shouldn't the cells contain null given that the formula inserts a "" (empty string)? I did check File/Options/Advanced and confirmed that zeroes were to be displayed. I also entered "=B243=0" into B246 and got FALSE, confirming that the blank cells didn't contain zero. Interestingly, if I modified the formula to fill vbNullString instead of """", the previously blank cells were now all zeroes. Sorting result  is different also. With """", after sorting, numbers started from row 2 and down. With vbNullString, numbers were at the bottom.

Comment: If B1 contains nothing the FIND function will be successful and the result imported from Sheet9 will be a zero if the referenced cell there is also blank. If B1 has a content that value may not be found in Sheet9 resulting in a *FIND* error which the formula converts to "". Note that "" = NullString. Your sorting result may be different depending upon whether you sort formulas or values.

Comment: I just ran your code on my sheet and got two numbers - 244, 244. This is exactly the same as what my code gave.

Comment: This is because in your test B1 isn't blank. Bear in mind that xlDown looks from the given cell down whereas xlUp looks from the given cell up. Therefore, in the case of xlDown, the result must be the the same as for xlUp if there are no blank cells before the end of the column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but this goes back to my original question. What's so special about row 244? B3 down till the end of the column are all empty. In fact, columns 2 to 199 from row 10 and down are all empty and End(xlUp) and End(xlDown) all give 244.

Comment: B244 is the last not empty (used) cell in column B. Please understand that Excel is all about displaying things in cells which aren't there. In this case the thing that's displayed is a null string and you try to argue that it can't be there because it doesn't exist and isn't visible. It's there because your own formula put it there. It isn't visible because null strings are invisible. The code we are discussing proves both facts.

Comment: Thanks. Now, it's beginning to make sense. Is there a way to remove null strings or differentiate cells that contain a null string and those that are empty?